# Why is the snake head jumping around?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been making the **snake game in python using tkinter** and I am pretty much done but I recently encountered a problem. I tried to define that if the user hits one of the directional buttons (the arrow keys or A,W,S,D) the snake's movement would be continued, which is how it is supposed to be. It works but when seen in action if the user changes the current direction the snake is heading the snake's head just jumps around and glitches. It is kind of a challenge now to catch a fruit in the game since the snake's head jumps around so much. Also because of the jumping around, the game leads to a game over scenario much easier. How can I fic this? My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random

root = Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TLabel", font=('Helvetica', 40, 'bold'))
root.geometry("737x300")
root.resizable(0, 0)

def StartGame(lbl_txt: str, btn_txt: str, canvas=None, score_lbl=None):
    # Just a function for the start of the game and the gameover
    pass
  
def game():
    main_x, main_y = 200, 160
    key = ""
    velocity = 20
    can_w, can_h = 600, 300
    grid_x, grid_y = [gx for gx in range(0, can_w, velocity)], [gy for gy in range(0, can_h, velocity)]
    cords_list = [[main_x, main_y]]
    tales = {}
    score = 0
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=can_w, height=can_h, bg="light blue")
    score_lbl = Label(root, text=f"Score: {score}", font=('Arial', 24, 'italic'))
    canvas.grid()
    score_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)
    canvas.create_rectangle(main_x, main_y, main_x + velocity, main_y + velocity, fill="purple", outline="purple")
    fruit_x, fruit_y = random.choice(grid_x), random.choice(grid_y)
    fruit = canvas.create_rectangle(fruit_x, fruit_y, fruit_x + velocity, fruit_y + velocity, fill="red", outline="red")

    def spawn():
        nonlocal fruit, fruit_x, fruit_y, score
        score += 1
        score_lbl.config(text=f"Score: {score}")
        canvas.delete(fruit)
        if key == "Up":
            cords_list.append([cords_list[-1][0], cords_list[-1][1] + velocity])
            tales.update({f"tale-{score}": canvas.create_rectangle(
                cords_list[-1][0], cords_list[-1][1], cords_list[-1][0] + velocity, cords_list[-1][1] + velocity
            )})
        elif key == "Down":
            cords_list.append([cords_list[-1][0], cords_list[-1][1] - velocity])
            tales.update({f"tale-{score}": canvas.create_rectangle(
                cords_list[-1][0], cords_list[-1][1], cords_list[-1][0] + velocity, cords_list[-1][1] + velocity
            )})
        elif key == "Left":
            cords_list.append([cords_list[-1][0] + velocity, cords_list[-1][1]])
            tales.update({f"tale-{score}": canvas.create_rectangle(
                cords_list[-1][0], cords_list[-1][1], cords_list[-1][0] + velocity, cords_list[-1][1] + velocity
            )})
        elif key == "Right":
            cords_list.append([cords_list[-1][0] - velocity, cords_list[-1][1]])
            tales.update({f"tale-{score}": canvas.create_rectangle(
                cords_list[-1][0], cords_list[-1][1], cords_list[-1][0] + velocity, cords_list[-1][1] + velocity
            )})

        fruit_x, fruit_y = random.choice(grid_x), random.choice(grid_y)
        fruit = canvas.create_rectangle(fruit_x, fruit_y, fruit_x + 20, fruit_y + 20, fill="red", outline="red")

    def up(event):
        nonlocal key
        if key != "Up":
            key = "Up"

            def move():
                if cords_list[0][1] > 0 and [cords_list[0][0], cords_list[0][1] - velocity] not in cords_list:
                    canvas.move(1, 0, -velocity)
                    # print([cords_list[0][0], cords_list[0][1] - velocity], cords_list)
                    for v in range(len(cords_list) - 1, 0, -1):
                        cords_list[v] = cords_list[v - 1].copy()
                    cords_list[0][1] -= velocity
                    for count in range(1, len(tales) + 1):
                        canvas.delete(tales[f"tale-{count}"])
                        tales[f"tale-{count}"] = canvas.create_rectangle(cords_list[count][0], cords_list[count][1],
                                                                         cords_list[count][0] + 20,
                                                                         cords_list[count][1] + 20)
                    if cords_list[0][0] == fruit_x and cords_list[0][1] == fruit_y:
                        spawn()

                    if key == "Up":
                        root.after(80, move)
                else:
                    StartGame("GAME OVER!", "Restart", canvas, score_lbl)

            move()

    def down(event):
        nonlocal key
        if key != "Down":
            key = "Down"

            def move():
                if cords_list[0][1] + 20 < can_h and [cords_list[0][0], cords_list[0][1] + velocity] not in cords_list:
                    canvas.move(1, 0, velocity)
                    for v in range(len(cords_list) - 1, 0, -1):
                        cords_list[v] = cords_list[v - 1].copy()
                    cords_list[0][1] += velocity
                    for count in range(1, len(tales) + 1):
                        canvas.delete(tales[f"tale-{count}"])
                        tales[f"tale-{count}"] = canvas.create_rectangle(cords_list[count][0], cords_list[count][1],
                                                                         cords_list[count][0] + 20,
                                                                         cords_list[count][1] + 20)
                    if cords_list[0][0] == fruit_x and cords_list[0][1] == fruit_y:
                        spawn()

                    if key == "Down":
                        root.after(80, move)
                else:
                    StartGame("GAME OVER!", "Restart", canvas, score_lbl)

            move()

    def left(event):
        nonlocal key
        if key != "Left":
            key = "Left"

            def move():
                if cords_list[0][0] > 0 and [cords_list[0][0] - velocity, cords_list[0][1]] not in cords_list:
                    canvas.move(1, -velocity, 0)
                    for v in range(len(cords_list) - 1, 0, -1):
                        cords_list[v] = cords_list[v - 1].copy()
                    cords_list[0][0] -= velocity
                    for count in range(1, len(tales) + 1):
                        canvas.delete(tales[f"tale-{count}"])
                        tales[f"tale-{count}"] = canvas.create_rectangle(cords_list[count][0], cords_list[count][1],
                                                                         cords_list[count][0] + 20,
                                                                         cords_list[count][1] + 20)
                    if cords_list[0][0] == fruit_x and cords_list[0][1] == fruit_y:
                        spawn()

                    if key == "Left":
                        root.after(80, move)
                else:
                    StartGame("GAME OVER!", "Restart", canvas, score_lbl)

            move()

    def right(event):
        nonlocal key
        if key != "Right":
            key = "Right"

            def move():
                if cords_list[0][0] + 20 < can_w and [cords_list[0][0] + velocity, cords_list[0][1]] not in cords_list:
                    canvas.move(1, velocity, 0)
                    for v in range(len(cords_list) - 1, 0, -1):
                        cords_list[v] = cords_list[v - 1].copy()
                    cords_list[0][0] += velocity
                    for count in range(1, len(tales) + 1):
                        canvas.delete(tales[f"tale-{count}"])
                        tales[f"tale-{count}"] = canvas.create_rectangle(cords_list[count][0], cords_list[count][1],
                                                                         cords_list[count][0] + 20,
                                                                         cords_list[count][1] + 20)
                    if cords_list[0][0] == fruit_x and cords_list[0][1] == fruit_y:
                        spawn()

                    if key == "Right":
                        root.after(80, move)
                else:
                    StartGame("GAME OVER!", "Restart", canvas, score_lbl)

            move()

    root.bind("<Up>", up)
    root.bind("<Key-w>", up)
    root.bind("<Key-W>", up)
    root.bind("<Down>", down)
    root.bind("<Key-s>", down)
    root.bind("<Key-S>", down)
    root.bind("<Left>", left)
    root.bind("<Key-a>", left)
    root.bind("<Key-A>", left)
    root.bind("<Right>", right)
    root.bind("<Key-d>", right)
    root.bind("<Key-D>", right)

game()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logical problem.

1. User presses UP key:

   - `key` is set to "Up"
   - snake moves 1 up
   - next `move()` is scheduled for now + 80ms
2. 80ms later snake moves up, next `move()` is scheduled for now + 80ms
3. 80ms later snake moves up, next `move()` is scheduled for now + 80ms
4. User presses LEFT key:

   - key is set to "Left"
   - snake moves 1 left
   - next left-`move()` is scheduled for now + 80ms
5. the scheduled "UP" `move()` from before the keypress is executed

   - snake wiggels 1 up and does not reschedule UP `move()` as key is now "Left"
6. 80ms since LEFT key press later:

   - snake moves 1 left
   - next `move()` is scheduled for now + 80ms

etc.

Simplest fix:

```
 def up(event):  
    nonlocal key
    if key != "Up":
        key = "Up"

        def move():
            if key != "Up": # same for left/right/down functions - do not execute
                            # movement if key got changed
                return
            if cords_list[0][1] > 0 and .... # the remainder of your code
```

Same for all other move events.

Comment: Thank you @Patrick Artner! It totally worked for me!